# Eclipse product issue with Juno - Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.e4.core.services

Tags: java, jar, swt, eclipse-juno, eclipse-indigo

We are using a SWT eclipse based app on Eclipse Indigo 3.x version. Now we plan to migrate to Eclipse Juno whcih is 4.x. I followed instructions from here - http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4MigrationGuide/article.html

After resolving few issues I am stuck at following exc.:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.103.0.v20120530-1824 [279]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.e4.core.services; bundle-version="1.0.0"
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(AbstractBundle.java:1332)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolutionFailureException(AbstractBundle.java:1316)
    ......
    ......
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.forms 4 0 2014-06-25 18:38:38.526
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The activator org.eclipse.ui.internal.forms.FormsPlugin for bundle org.eclipse.ui.forms is invalid
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:172)
    ....
....
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/ui/plugin/AbstractUIPlugin
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:188)
    .....
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:165)
    ... 12 more
```

My config.ini file:

```
eclipse.product=com.lehman.cmte.amm.prop.grid.client.product
osgi.splashPath=platform:/base/plugins/com.lehman.cmte.amm.prop.grid.client
osgi.bundles=org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt_0.10.1.v20120523-    1955.jar@start,org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.6.100.v20120522-  1841.jar@start,org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.0.v20120522-1841.jar@start,org.eclipse.equinox.event_1.2.200.v20120522-2049.jar@start,org.eclipse.equinox.util_1.0.400.v20120522-2049.jar@start,org.eclipse.ui.forms_3.5.200.v20120521-2329.jar@start,org.eclipse.ui.intro_3.4.200.v20120521-2344.jar@start,org.eclipse.e4.core.services_1.0.0.v20120521-2346.jar@start,org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.8.0.v20120521-2346.jar@start,org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.103.0.v20120530-1824.jar@start
osgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4
eof=eof
```

I have org.eclipse.e4.core.services version 1.0.0 in plugins and have included it in config.ini.

What am I missing?

I am really clueless after spending lot of time in debugging the issue.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**
Made changes after comments from @greg-449

issue is that I am getting exc: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart but I have required plugin under dependencies.

My xxx.product file has plugins radio button selected under tab Overview>Product Definition.
Do I need to provide the plugins list somewhere else too? like MANIFEST.MF? If I see Plugins tab under Run configurations, Add required plugins button is enabled and I have already included plugins in Run config by clicking that button and it has org.eclipse.ui.workbench_xxx.jar which contains class org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart

**Any pointer ??**

Comment: Are you using a xxx.product file to create the RCP?

Comment: Yes. I am using .product file and in Configuration tab, I have provided my config.ini file which is given in my original post. FYI, everything works fine with Eclipse Indigo 3.x but not with Juno 4.x

Comment: It is easier to let Eclipse generate the config.ini for you by selecting 'Generate a default config.ini'. Make sure to click 'Add Required' on the Dependencies tab to get all required plugins included.

Comment: Thanks. If I use autogenerate feature for ini file, my app comes up but where shall I provide required plugins? For sake of safety, I added all plugins under eclipse/plugin dir to xxx.product file under Dependencies tab. My xxx.product file has plugins radio button selected under tab Overview>Product Definition...... issue is that I am getting exc: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart but I have required plugin under dependencies.

Comment: You normally just put your plugins in to the Dependencies and then click 'Add Required'.

Comment: I tried that initially but that option is disabled. Don't know why. But anyways adding all plugins shouldn't hurt just for testing purpose. As you pointed out Adding required plugins, how eclipse will come to know required plugins during application launch? Do I need to provide the plugins list somewhere else too? like MANIFEST.MF? If I see Plugins tab under Run configurations, Add required plugins button is enabled and I have already included plugins in Run config by clicking that button and it has org.eclipse.ui.workbench_xxx.jar which contains class org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.